# Databricks SQL, error when running update with join

Tags: databricks, databricks-sql

I am trying to run an update on a Delta table and I am getting the following error.

```
Error in SQL statement: ParseException: 
mismatched input 'from' expecting <EOF>(line 3, pos 0)
```

I really can't figure out why I get this error. Can anyone help me?

```
update eff
set eff.ACP = ia.COSTVALUE
from views.test_acp_effect eff
left join source_tables_db.ia_master_items ia 
on eff.CODE = ia.IMM_CODE
where eff.DXN_Period = (
        select td.MY_FISCAL_PERIOD_ABBR
        from timedelta td
        where current_date() between td.MIN_P_DATE
                and td.MAX_P_DATE
        )
    and eff.CODE = source_tables_db.ia_master_items.IMM_CODE
```

Comment: views - sounds like a keyword. Did you try moving that table to another database?

Comment: @GaneshChandrasekaran That that did not help but I was able to achieve my goal by using a CTE and the merge into statement.